# Workspace created by Cocoapods won't open

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, xcode6.3

I have an existing project that was working just a few weeks ago. I recently tried to open the workspace that cocoa pods created and it just spins on "loading" forever in Xcode 6.3. I deleted the project file and ran pod install to create a new one and got the exact same result.

Anyone else running into this? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with swift playgrounds included in the project. Once removed, it all works properly.